# How can I calculate this limit: $\lim\limits_{x\to 0} x\left\lfloor\frac{1}{x}\right\rfloor$?

Tags: calculus, limits, ceiling-and-floor-functions

Calculate the following limit.
$$
\lim_{x\to 0} x\left\lfloor\frac{1}{x}\right\rfloor
$$
Where $\left\lfloor x \right\rfloor$ represents greatest integer function or floor function, i.e greatest integer less than or equal to $x$.

Thanks.

Comment: Are the square brackets just brackets, or do they refer to something like the integer part, floor or ceiling? Please clarify.

Comment: @CliveNewstead I edited to make it the floor function. That's just a guess, but it often what $[x]$ means, and I doubt OP just means them as parentheses.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

In case $[x]$ is intended to be an integer part of $x$, you have
$$
  \lim_{x\to 0}x\left[\frac1x\right] = \lim_{y\to\infty}\frac{[y]}{y} = \lim_{y\to\infty}\frac{y -\{y\}}y = 1.
$$

Comment: Proving that $\lim_{y\to\infty}\frac{\lfloor y \rfloor}{y} = 1$ only proves that $\lim_{x\to 0^\color{red}{+}} x \left\lfloor\frac{1}{x}\right\rfloor = 1$. A similar argument is needed for the limit for below.

Comment: @jjagmath those were long 10 years. I might have meant unsigned infinity perhaps

Answer (score 8):

If $\frac1x=n+y$ where $n$ is any integer and $ 0\le y<1,\implies  \left[\frac1x\right]=n$

So, $x \left[\frac1x\right]=\frac n{n+y}=\frac1{1+\frac yn}$

As $x\to 0$ and  $ 0\le y<1, n\to\infty\implies \lim_{x\to 0}x \left[\frac1x\right]=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac1{1+\frac yn}=1$

Answer (score 5):

Consider $x \in (1/(n+1),1/n]$. We then have $\dfrac1x \in [n,n+1)$. Hence, $\left\lfloor \dfrac1x \right\rfloor = n$. Hence, we have
$$x \left\lfloor \dfrac1x \right\rfloor \in \left(\dfrac{n}{n+1},1\right]$$
Argue similarly, for $x \to 0^{-}$. Now use the above to show that
$$\lim_{x \to 0} x \left\lfloor \dfrac1x \right\rfloor = 1$$

Answer (score 5):

Use one basic inequality concerning integer part
$$\frac{1}{x}\leq \left\lfloor\frac{1}{x}\right\rfloor\leq \frac{1}{x}+1$$

\begin{align}
1 \leq x\left\lfloor\frac{1}{x}\right\rfloor\leq 1+x \,\mathrm{if}\, x>0\\
1\geq x\left\lfloor\frac{1}{x}\right\rfloor\geq 1+x \,\mathrm{if}\, x<0
\end{align}
So by squeeze theorem $$\lim _{n\rightarrow 0}x\left\lfloor\frac{1}{x}\right\rfloor=1.$$

Comment: I Believe this should be $$\frac{1}{x}-1\leq \left\lfloor\frac{1}{x}\right\rfloor\leq \frac{1}{x}$$