# Evaluate $\lim_{x \to 0} (x\lfloor\frac{1}{x}\rfloor)$

Tags: calculus, limits, ceiling-and-floor-functions

Evaluate $\lim_{x \to 0} (x\lfloor\frac{1}{x}\rfloor)$

I'm trying to solve it by using the squeeze theorem but I'm stuck.

I'm looking for a function $g(x)$ such that $g(x) \leq x\lfloor\frac{1}{x}\rfloor \leq x(\frac{1}{x}) = 1$

Can anybody give me a hint?

Comment: I would consider this expression on the left and right of $0$ separately, and only look at small values of $x$ (less than $1$ in magnitude). Also, your second inequality isn't true for all $x$ (consider the value of $x\lfloor\frac1x\rfloor$ for $x=-\frac12$).

Comment: I realize now that I should consider it separately. Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: Notice that $|\lfloor1/x\rfloor-1/x|$ is bounded.

Comment: See also: [How can I calculate this limit: $\lim\limits_{x\to 0} x\left\lfloor\frac{1}{x}\right\rfloor$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/345868)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Limit involving floor function: $\lim\limits_{x\to 0} x \left\lfloor\frac1x \right\rfloor$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3412106/limit-involving-floor-function-lim-limits-x-to-0-x-left-lfloor-frac1x-rig)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

By definition,
$$\frac{1}{x} - 1 < \left\lfloor \frac{1}{x} \right\rfloor \leq \frac{1}{x}.$$

- If $x > 0$, this implies $1 - x \le x \lfloor \frac{1}{x} \rfloor \le 1$, so by squeezing you get $\lim_{x \to 0^+} x \lfloor 1/x \rfloor = 1$.
- If $x < 0$, the inequalities are reversed: $1 - x \ge x \lfloor \frac{1}{x} \rfloor \ge 1$ and again by squeezing it follows that $\lim_{x \to 0^-} x \lfloor 1/x \rfloor = 1$.

The RHS limit and the LHS limit exist and are equal, thus $\lim_{x \to 0} x \lfloor 1/x \rfloor = 1$.

Comment: Oh okay, I see what that gives me. For some reason I wasn't satisfied with having the $<$ instead of $\leq$ because I did not consider that it could result in an answer after I multiplied by $x$. Thank you, Najib Idrissi.

Comment: This assumes that $x\gt0$. For $x\lt0$, the inequalities on the right side of the $\implies$ are reversed. One can still squeeze, but it is worth mentioning.

Comment: @robjohn Should be correct now.

Answer (score 5):

Here is an approach. We recall the identity

> $$ \lfloor y\rfloor = y - \{y\}  $$

where $ \{y\} $ is the fractional part of $y$ which has the property $ \{y\}<1. $

Let $y=\frac{1}{x}$ so the limit becomes

> $$ \lim_{y\to \infty} \frac{y - \{y\}}{y} = 1-\lim_{y\to \infty} \frac{\{y\}}{y}=1-0=1.  $$

Comment: That's a cool approach. I've never seen that identity being used before.

Comment: @KermittheHermit: It makes the problem so simple.