# Solving $\lim\limits_{x \to \infty}\frac{x-[x]}{x}$

Tags: calculus, limits

Solve :$$\lim_{x \to \infty}\frac{x-[x]}{x}$$ where $[x]$ is the floor function ( the greatest integer function) . Now, i what know is that $x-1<[x]\le x$ and I was thinking to apply the squeeze theorem. The answer that I get is $0$. Is this correct ?

Comment: surely the denominator, which is the fractional part of $x$, is limited to be in $[0,1)$, so the limit is obvious

Comment: Thank you, just wanted to double-check .

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3517293/find-the-limit-lim-x-to-0-x-left-left-frac1x-right-left-frac2x

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$$\frac{x-[x]}{x}=1-\frac{[x]}{x},$$
and $ x-1\leq [x]\leq x$, i.e. $$\frac{x-1}{x}\leq \frac{[x]}{x}\leq 1.$$
Therefore $$\lim_{x\to \infty }1-\frac{[x]}{x}=0.$$

Comment: you mean $[x]\leq x$

Comment: No, $[x]$ is the greatest integer function, i.e. for example $[3.1]=4$ @SK19

Comment: OP explicitly said it was the floor function and wrote the inequality themselves. It's "greatest integer smaller or equal to the number", so $[3.1]=3$.

Comment: @SK19: Sorry, my english is not so good, I got confused. Indeed, you right. I correct it.